# When an instance of an object has it's value read, how to catch that and send something other then the object definition?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class that has two attributes, x and y. When I need the value of an instance of that class, instead of returning the class decerator, I need to output a list. I have circumvented this by defining a static method within it, but there is probably a better way to do this.

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    @staticmethod
    def val(self):
        return [self.x,self.y]
```

Currently, in order to get the value in the manner that I want, here is what has to happen:

```
foo = Vector(2,2)
print(Vector.val(foo))
```

Comment: Depending on how you're using it, I don't see anything too off about this (although a tuple may be a better fit here instead of a list). Why make it a static method though? Why not just make it an instance method then `print(foo.val())`? What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way for me to get the value like `print(foo)`, and it would print the list.

Comment: Does it need to be a list, or does it just need to be an iterable?

Comment: Any iterable would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to allow objects of your class to be iterated, you can give the class an `__iter__` method:

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y
```

In this case, `__iter__` is a generator function. Each time `next` is called on the produced iterator, it will return `x`, then `y`, then stop.

You could also make it more vanilla by cheating and returning an iterator of a list wrapping the elements:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter([self.x, self.y])
```

Now the class itself is iterable:

```
for x in Vector(1, 2):
    print(x)

# 1
# 2
```

If you want to `print` it nicely though, you'll need to unpack the iterator first:

```
print(*Vector(1, 2))  # 1 2
```